# Attempting to concatenate a variable into an img source, but it ignores the variable

Tags: javascript, this, concatenation, src

```
var tmp = "";

function putItem()
{
    this.innerHTML = "<img src = 'image/"+tmp+".png'>";
}
```

---

I also have a  `td`  that calls this

```
<img src = 'images/wood.png' onclick = 'tmp = "wood";'>
<td onclick = "grid1 = tmp; checkEmpty(); putItem(this);">
```

---

I tested it by making the `"<img src = 'image/"+tmp+".png'>";` a variable and when I returned what the variable was when tmp wasnt an empty string it came out as `"<img src = 'image/.png'>"` ie it ignored the tmp.

Any help?

I'm trying to make the "Minecraft (c) Crafting Table" for a web dev project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Question changed.*** Now it seems that the only issue is that you need to use `.call` to set the `this` value in `putItem`.

```
<img src = 'images/wood.png' onclick = 'tmp = "wood";'>
<td onclick = "grid1 = tmp; checkEmpty(); putItem.call(this);">
```

---

---

***Original answer***

I assume instead of this...

```
              <!--   v---- assign empty string to global grid1 variable -->
<td onclick = "grid1 = tmp; checkEmpty(); putItem(this);">
```

You want this...

```
          <!--     v---- assign "grid1" string to global tmp variable -->
<td onclick = "tmp = 'grid1'; checkEmpty(); putItem.call(this);">
          <!-- set the value of "this" in "putItem"---^  -->
```

So now you're assigning the `"grid1"` string to the `tmp` variable, and when you call `putItem()`, you're using `.call` to set its `this` value.

---

That said, instead of using a global variable, why not just *pass* the string?

```
function putItem( str ) {
    this.innerHTML = "<img src = 'image/" + str + ".png'>";
}
```

---

```
<td onclick = "checkEmpty(); putItem.call(this, 'grid1');">
```

Comment: No I don't tmp is an object I'm trying to put into grid1.
I have grid1 as global variable that also needs to recieve tmp

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion: Alright, I'll update. If the image is being clicked first, then you just need to set the `this` value in the `putItem` function using `.call`.

Comment: I need to keep track of what `grid1` is, and I'm assigning the `tmp` variable to grid1. Ugh maybe I should put what the thing is suppose to be h/o
can you give an example of how `.call` should be used? I don't know how that method is used.

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion: The `.call()` method is simply an alternate way of invoking a function that lets you set the value of `this` in the function. So the way you had it, in your `putItem` function, `this` will be a reference to `window`. But if you do `putItem.call(this)`, since `this` in your inline `onclick` handler will be the element clicked, using `.call(this)` will make `this` in `putItem` the same value.

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion: You're welcome. If it helps, [here's a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/ANG5G/) that calls the same function twice. The function alerts `this`. The first time it doesn't use `.call`, the second time it does, and pass a string as the first argument. You'll see that in the second call, the value of `this` is that string.